# How to upload module to Bintray using custom artifact name?

Tags: android, maven, android-library, bintray, jcenter

I've used the following standard code to upload my library to bintray.

I have two modules, a 'sample' module for testing and a 'library' module. I want to use a custom artifactId when I upload this to bintray but instead the artifactId gets changed to "library" (the module name) and I don't want this!

I know I could rename my "library" module to the desired name but I also want to keep this structure of module names.

I want something like: `com.mydomain.something:CUSTOM-NAME:version`.
And NOT something like: `com.mydomain.something:LIBRARY:version`.

```
ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'MyLibrary'

    // Maven metadata
    publishedGroupId = 'com.domain.name'
    libraryName = 'MyLibrary'
    artifact = 'custom-name'

    libraryDescription = 'description'
    libraryVersion = '0.0.1'

    developerId = 'someone'
    developerName = 'someone'
    developerEmail = 'someone@gmail.com'
}
```

I know all of this is possible since I've seen a couple of repositories using this module name structure and having "custom" artifactId on bintray/JCenter.

Example:

- [Library 1](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)
- [Library 2](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @Flitskikker see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is add

```
archivesBaseName = 'myartifactid'
```

to your `library` module gradle file. This will rename all archive outputs, so not only aar but also javadoc and sources, for example.

Comment: after adding this code it pushes files in different folders on bintray: one part in library folder and another to myartifactid

Comment: Used to work correctly. It might be that this doesn't work anymore with newer versions of the Gradle plugin.

Answer (score 0):

**Using the Bintray release plugin**

When using `com.novoda:bintray-release`, use `artifactId` instead of `artifact` in `build.gradle` `publish` configuration:

```
publish {
    // ...
    artifactId = sporkArtifactId
    // ...
}
```

**Using your second example's gradle-maven-push**

See the [build.gradle](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/library/build.gradle) that applies [gradle-mvn-push.gradle](https://raw.github.com/chrisbanes/gradle-mvn-push/master/gradle-mvn-push.gradle)

The settings are defined in [gradle.properties](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/library/gradle.properties):

```
POM_NAME=FloatingActionButton
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=floatingactionbutton
POM_PACKAGING=aar
```